# Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($function) must be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, post-type

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdkBR.png

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1
> ($function) must be a valid callback, class Wcore_Admin does not have
> a method "sitemap_exclude_post_type" in
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292 Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(212): WP_Hook->apply_filters() #1
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/sitemaps/class-post-type-sitemap-provider.php(276):
> apply_filters() #2
> /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/sitemaps/class-post-type-sitemap-provider.php(253):
> WPSEO_Post_Type_Sitemap_Provider->is_valid_post_type() #3
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(294):
> WPSEO_Post_Type_Sitemap_Provider->save_post() #4
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(316):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters() #5 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(484):
> WP_Hook->do_action() #6 /var/www/html/wp-includes/post.php(4384):
> do_action() #7 /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/post.php(690):
> wp_insert_post() #8 /var/www/html/wp-admin/post-new.php(66):
> get_default_post_to_edit() #9 {main} thrown in
> /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292 There has been
> a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email
> inbox for instructions.

My server has been upgraded from PHP 7.4 to 8.0.8. I know it causes because of one of the plugins named wcore admin which was developed by custom. And It's required plugin to do our jobs. I'm looking for a way to fix the issues and maintain the script myself since I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
call_user_func_array([new $this->controller, $this->action], array $args);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue on upgrade to php8.0, the error shows steps to debug

**'class Wcore_Admin does not have a method "sitemap_exclude_post_type"'**

the plugin or file class name Wcore_Admin does not have a function named sitemap_exclude_post_type. Remove the line calling a missing function, and it should work

Comment: I had to revert back to php7.4 and everything started working normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the php version to 7.4.30 and this solved my issue